# How can I simplify my jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

And if you could provide a small explanation of what you can clearly see I am misunderstanding, that would be excellent!

```
$('#my_select11').change(function () {
$('#my_quest').css( 'color', $(this).val() );
})
$('#my_select12').change(function () {
$('#my_clock').css( 'color', $(this).val() );
})
</script>


<td>
            <div class="styled-select">
            <select id="my_select11">
                <option value="#0079C2"></option>
                <option value="#004b77"></option>
                <option value="#EE7B2C"></option>
                <option value="#EE7C2E"> </option>
                <option value="#CF641A"></option>
                <option value="#333"></option>
                <option value="#666"></option>
                <option value="#DAD9D9"></option>
                <option value="#FAFAFA"></option>
            </select>                       
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

This is essentially a table full of selects. Each time you click on a select to change the value, it changes the fa fa-awesome (my_mobile) etc, to the chosen value.

Comment: I think the keyword of the day is [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)

Comment: WHen learning jQuery is always easiest to learn how to use ID selector. Start learning how to use common classes on common elements and using  traverses or indexing. Would likely cut what you have down to about 4 lines. Need to show html basic structure in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give all your `<select>` elements a data attribute that indicates which other element's color should be changed. And give them all the same class so you can write a single handler.

```js
$(".color").change(function() {
  $($(this).data("rel")).css("color", $(this).val());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Question color:
<select class="color" data-rel="#my_quest">
  <option value="">--Choose--</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
<br/>
Clock color:
<select class="color" data-rel="#my_clock">
  <option value="">--Choose--</option>
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>
<br/>
<div id="my_quest">Question</div>
<div id="my_clock">Clock</div>
```